# How to use browser sync external url with PHP in android?

Tags: php, joomla, gulp, cross-browser, browser-sync

I've tried to open my joomla site in the Android browser with browserSync external URL.
I use wamp to run the server on pc.Is there a way to set up PHP and a web server on an Android device ?
How can I run joomla or php site on my Android device with browserSync ?

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FedBG.jpg)

[external url in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVvtv.jpg)

my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
watch = require('gulp-watch'),
postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
cssVars = require('postcss-advanced-variables'),
cssImport = require('postcss-import'),
nested = require('postcss-nested'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('styles', function() {
var processors = [
    cssImport,
    cssVars,
    nested,
    autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions']
    })
];
return gulp.src('./assets/styles/styles.css')
    .pipe(postcss(processors))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./temp/styles'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {

browserSync.init({
    proxy: "localhost/j2shop",
    port: 8080,
    notify: false,
    watchTask: true,
    debugInfo: true,
    logConnections: true

});

watch('./assets/includes/**/*.php', function() {
    browserSync.reload();
});

watch('./assets/styles/**/*.css', function() {
    gulp.start('cssInject');
});
});

gulp.task('cssInject', ['styles'], function() {
  return gulp.src('./temp/styles/styles.css')
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run `gulp`. That will start Browsersync running and it will report to you in Terminal what the external url to enter on your device is. It will be something like http://10.0.1.12:3000. Just enter that on your Android and you will see your site.